# mesh.colors not working. Mesh is white

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a procedural terrain generation system and I wanted to make it have a low poly effect. I tried using a texture for colours, but it wasn't what I was looking for. Instead I've decided to assign the colours of the triangles individually, and I'm having an issue with that.

Here is my code for creating the mesh.

```
public Mesh CreateMesh()
{
    Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangles;
    mesh.uv = uvs;

    Color[] colours = new Color[vertices.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i++)
    {
        int vertIndex = triangles[i];
        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            colours[vertIndex] = Color.green;
        }
    }

    mesh.colors = colours;

    if (useFlatShading)
    {
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }
    else
    {
        mesh.normals = bakedNormals;
    }

    return mesh;
}
```

I am using Color.green temporarily. Here is the code I'm using for flat shading to give it the low poly effect:

```
void FlatShading()
{
    Vector3[] flatShadedVertices = new Vector3[triangles.Length];
    Vector2[] flatShadedUvs = new Vector2[triangles.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i++)
    {
        flatShadedVertices[i] = vertices[triangles[i]];
        flatShadedUvs[i] = uvs[triangles[i]];
        triangles[i] = i;
    }

    vertices = flatShadedVertices;
    uvs = flatShadedUvs;
}
```

Can anyone see an issue. If not, I will search through my code some more and try and figure it out.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: Flatshading is called BEFORE CreateMesh, so the new vertices and uvs are calculated before being assigned to the mesh itself.

Comment: What does not working mean? Any error? What did you get, what did you expect? Imo you should fill the whole color array with a color and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Had my shader on Unlit/Texture so it was expecting a texture. My bad!